# What is an appropriate way to handle API loop with progress indicator?

Tags: ios, json, api, afnetworking, response

Server is currently returning `100 items` in an array plus with additional pagination information like how many `total pages` are there. Request parameter is also accepting `current page` to return appropriate items.

I have to display a `progress indicator` based on `current page` progress and fetch.

For example: I have received `100 items` with `total pages = 4` by making api call with request parameter `page = 1.`
Then I can make another looped api calls with current page = 2,3 and 4 but there would be a problem in progress indicator that it can't pre-assume the total pages without receiving 1st API response.

What would be the appropriate way to handle such loop api calls ?

I think we need another api call which will return total pages first and then i can handle my progress indicator in advance and keep on updating progress based on results.

Comment: Why not simply set the maximum for the progress bar once you have the first response back. Until that point the progress is 0 anyway